# Issue to Merge ResourceDictionary in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
            {
                case "de-DE":
                    var German = new Uri("..\\GlobalString\\Dictionary_de-DE.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = German });
                    break;
                case "it-IT":
                    var Italy = new Uri("..\\GlobalString\\Dictionary_it-IT.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = Italy });
                    break;
                case "es-ES":
                    var Spanish = new Uri("..\\GlobalString\\Dictionary_es-ES.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = Spanish });
                    break;
                case "fr-FR":
                    var France = new Uri("..\\GlobalString\\Dictionary_fr-FR.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = France });
                    break;
                default:
                    var English = new Uri("..\\GlobalString\\Dictionary_de-DE.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = English });
                    break;
            }   
        }
    }
```

First I merged the all dictionaries and Then i tried to dynamically get the value from Dictionary like below.But it is showing Error(**'MyString' resource not found**).

```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      string StringFromDictionary= Application.Current.FindResource("MyString");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For English it shows de-DE. Are you a copy-paste victim ?

Not sure for WPF but in silverlight Application.Current.Resources["MyString"] works.

Beside this you add into Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries so Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries["My String"] may also work for you.

Maybe FindResource just look for Application.Current.Resources ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

- I doubt `Application.Current` is usable in `App`'s constructor as `Application.Current` is supposed to end up being `App` itself. Try using `this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add` instead.
- Is there anything in your "App.xaml" ? If so it will replace `App.Resources` and all you have set up in the constructor is lost.

Comment: I tried as you said Even though it is not work.If i merge the dictionary in Window_Loaded Event means, It will working well.If i follow this step means,I have to merge the dictionary in all window where i need to get String value from Resource Dictionary.